# Question about Quotient space, regarding The left coset space of group $G$ with respect to a subgroup $H$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ is a left topological group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Denote by $G/H$ the set of all left cosets 
$aH$ of $H$ in $G$ (for each $a\in G$), and endow it with the quotient topology with respect to the canonical mapping $\pi$.

Then the space $G/H$ is called the left coset space of $G$ with respect to $H$.

> A left topological group consists of a group $G$ and a topology $\mathfrak{T}$ on the set $G$ 
>   such that for all $a\in G$, the left action $\mathfrak{l}_a$ of $a$ on $G$ is a continuous mapping of the space $G$ 
>   to itself.

It is not true that a quotient map is necessarily open([Example of quotient mapping that is not open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655797/example-of-quotient-mapping-that-is-not-open)) but in this case, why $\pi$ is open?

**EDIT:** 
The following theorem Notes that, $\pi$ is open; But i do not understand why?

Thank you for taking the time.

[image: ‎A‎. ‎Arhangel'skii and M‎. ‎Tkachenko‎, Topological Groups and Related Structures‎, ‎Atlantis Press‎, ‎2008‎.]

Comment: Is it not simply that  $\pi^{-1} (\pi U) = U H$? The latter is open, if $U$ is open, agree?

Comment: @peterag yeah $\pi^{-1} (\pi U) = U H$, but $UH$ is open in $G$ ? ($G$ is a left topological group. $HU$ is open in $G$.)

Comment: OOPS - I hadn't noticed the "LEFT" in the question. Apologies! So what are the definitions: presumably $ h\mapsto g h $ is cts, but I presume that $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is also cts?

Comment: @peterag  If inversion were assumed to be continuous, then there would be no meaning to the 'left' in the definition as $hg = (g^{-1}h^{-1})^{-1}$ and then right multiplication would also be continuous.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch - yes, thanks... my fingers typed faster than my small mind could follow, but I did see once I hit 'enter'.... ah well.

Comment: @peterag That is, Every left topological group $G$ with continuous inverse is a semitopological group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the following.

*Counterexample.* Let $G=F(x,y)$ be the free group with two generators $x$ and $y$ and $p$ be a prime number. Let $\mathcal B=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ be the base of the unit of a left topological group $(G,\tau)$, where $U_n=\{x^{mp^n}: m\in\Bbb Z\}$. That is a family $\{gU_n: g\in G, n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a base of the topology $\tau$. Now put $H=\{y^m:m\in\Bbb Z\}$. It is easy to check that a set $U_1H=\pi^{-1}\pi(U_1)$ is not open, so a set $\pi(U_1)$ is not open in the quotient topology too.

The existence of a counterexample to a theorem from Arhangel'skii and Tkachenko’s book seems strange, so I’ll ask my teacher, who is a disciple of Arhangel’skii, about this contradiction.

Comment: I really appreciate your concern.